# Stick DIV with CSS Class at top after scroll using javascript - example provided

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to stick a DIV to the top of the page with JS. But because the DIV is susceptible to automatic updates, I have to use the included CSS Class(es). rather than add an ID as one is not available.

I've looked on W3 Schools, but can't find a solution.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function sticky_relocate() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
    if (window_top > div_top) {
        $("CSSCLASS").addClass('stick');
        $('#sticky-anchor').height($("CSSCLASS").outerHeight());
    } else {
        $("CSSCLASS").removeClass('stick');
        $('#sticky-anchor').height(0);
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/themysticalsock/2u5qy0th/

P.S. Please ignore the fact that my class is in caps, it's just to show in the example where I thought I would put it.

Comment: You are required to post your markup here, not a jsfiddle which can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one: [mcve]

Comment: JS fiddle is on my account and I'm not going to change it. So it's doing neither of those.

Also a JS Fiddle adds iterations after the subfolder like /1, /2 etc. so changes won't be to the original Fiddle.

Comment: YOU ARE REQUIRED TO POST YOUR MARKUP HERE, **NOT A JSFIDDLE!!!** [mcve]

Comment: Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all beware of the class selector in jQuery, it's:

```
$(".CSSCLASS").addClass('stick');
```

not

```
$("CSSCLASS").addClass('stick');
```

Than looks to me that your CSS should be:

```
.stick {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  border-radius: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
}
```

check the jsFeedle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2u5qy0th/6/